# При запуске gulp в терминале появляется ошибка: Error in plugin 'sass'.Error: Argument $file-formats was passed both by position and by name

Tags: gulp, sass

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться:
При запуске gulp в терминале появляется ошибка:

```
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    catalog\view\theme\olivia\stylesheet\_fonts.sass
Error: Argument $file-formats was passed both by position and by name.
  ╷
4 │ +font-face("roboto", "../fonts/RobotoBold/RobotoBold", bold, $file-formats:
woff)
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^
  ╵
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulpversion    = '4'; // Gulp version: 3 or 4

// Подключаем Gulp и все необходимые библиотеки
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
        gutil          = require('gulp-util' ),
        sass           = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
        browserSync    = require('browser-sync'),
        cleanCSS       = require('gulp-clean-css'),
        autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        bourbon        = require('bourbon'),
        ftp            = require('vinyl-ftp');

// Обновление страниц сайта на локальном сервере
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: "opencart.loc",
        notify: false
    });
});

// Компиляция stylesheet.css
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('catalog/view/theme/olivia/stylesheet/stylesheet.sass')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: bourbon.includePaths
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('catalog/view/theme/olivia/stylesheet/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('code', function() {
    return gulp.src(['catalog/view/theme/olivia/template/**/*.tpl'])
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});

// Выгрузка изменений на хостинг
gulp.task('deploy', function() {
    var conn = ftp.create({
        host:      'hostname.com',
        user:      'username',
        password:  'userpassword',
        parallel:  10,
        log: gutil.log
    });
    var globs = [
    'catalog/view/theme/olivia/**'
    ];
    return gulp.src(globs, {buffer: false})
    .pipe(conn.dest('/path/to/folder/on/server'));
});

// Наблюдение за файлами

if (gulpversion == 3) {
    gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function() {
        gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/olivia/stylesheet/stylesheet.sass', ['sass']);
    

        gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/olivia/template/**/*.tpl', browserSync.reload);
            gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/olivia/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
            gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/olivia/libs/**/*', browserSync.reload);
        });
        gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
    }

if (gulpversion == 4) {
    gulp.task('watch', function() {
        gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/olivia/stylesheet/stylesheet.sass', gulp.parallel('sass'));
        gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/olivia/template/**/*.tpl', gulp.parallel('code'));
        gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/olivia/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
        gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/olivia/libs/**/*', browserSync.reload);
    });
    gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('sass', 'browser-sync', 'watch'));
}
```

скриншот _front.sass:https://imgur.com/a/nyBsEez

Файл stylesheet.css не создается.